# Having trouble with C# form passing

Tags: c#

I'm currently trying to get into C#, after doing a ton of Java. I wanted to pass my GUI Form to another class, but I run into some trouble trying to access its containers etc. from there.

This is the autogenerated Form class:

```
namespace Wecker
{
    public partial class WeckerDesign : Form
    {
        public WeckerDesign()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            new WeckerRun(this);
        }
    }
}
```

and this is the recieving class:

```
namespace Wecker
{
    class WeckerRun
    {
        WeckerDesign wdesign = new WeckerDesign();

        public WeckerRun(WeckerDesign wdesign)
        {

            this.wdesign = wdesign;
            new DisplayClock(wdesign);
        }
    }
}
```

However, when I am trying to access the container "clockfield" from the recieving class, I can't find it. However, in the passing class, I can easily get there with this.clockpanel. ... and so on.

The recieving class won't even suggest me that. In Java, I would simply pass down my class as a whole with "this" in order to have the exact same reference in the other class, which I can treat as if I would do it in the original class where I got that object reference from.

How do I do this in C#?

Comment: Apart from being a bad practice to allow an external class reach the internal components of a form, do you have changed the access modifier of the 'container' from protected/private to public?

Comment: Thank you, I found it! That was pretty hidden, actually. Why do you mean it's a bad habit? How would you do it in C#, if you want to outsource some of your code which works on certain panels, in order to keep your classes somewhat clean and tidy? Or are you refering to the fact that I try to pass the whole form instead of especially extracted contents of the form?

Comment: At first, without knowing anything about your requirements, I would use an user control and place it in every form where I need it. I consider this form passing a bad practice because you couple the first form with the second one but now the second form cannot be used without the first one, instead a user control is a class by itself that provides a functionality to its callers. Of course this could all be wrong without knowing the details of your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How is your "clockpanel" field or property defined?  It will need to be public to be accessible from outside the class.